# how to use try accept in a better way while making an object of model class to get data?

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models, django-views

looking for help to handle the exception in a better way, I am new to python and django so if any one can suggest me that what can i write in place of pass, as i dont have any code to write there can i return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK) where pass is written or is there any thing which is better than this ?

```
if(computedsignature==signature):
            try:
               order=Orders.objects.get(id=id)
            except (Orders.DoesNotExist):
                pass 
            payment_collection_webhook_url=order.payment_collection_webhook_url
            application_id = order.applications
            try:
                application = Applications.objects.get(id=application_id)
            except (Applications.DoesNotExist):
                pass
            if(transaction_status=='SUCCESS'):
                try:
                    payment= Payments.objects.get(orders=order,direction=direction)
                except (Payments.DoesNotExist):
                    payment.save()
```

Comment: Why do you wrap these in `try`-`except`? If the payment can not be found, then likely something is *wrong*, and thus you returns something like a HTTP 404 response.

Comment: try to return some meaningful error messages and status codes in the `except` block

Answer (score 0):

It does not make much sense to wrap the result of database queries in a `try`-`except`. If it `Order` can not be found or the `Payment`, etc. then clearly something is wrong with the request, or with your view.

Usually it is better *not* to silence exceptions, since then it looks like everything works fine. But if no `Order` can be found, likely something is broken, or someone is attempting for example to hack the system and get an order for free.

One can work with the [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) to return HTTP 404 in case the query is missing, thus:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

if computedsignature == signature:
    order = get_object_or_404(Orders, id=id)
    payment_collection_webhook_url = order.payment_collection_webhook_url
    application = get_object_or_404(Applications, pk=order.applications)
    if transaction_status == 'SUCCESS':
        payment = get_object_or_404(Payments, orders=order,direction=direction)
    else:
        raise Http404('the payment was not successful')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat your exceptions in some way, otherwise your `try-except` clause has no sense.

Here you have two common examples:

```py
# If the object does not exists a HTTP 404 is returned.
try:
    your_model_instance = YourModel.objects.get(id=your_model_id)
except YourModel.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404()

# Equivalent simpler code.
your_model_instance = get_object_or_404(YourModel, id=your_model_id)
```

```py
# If the object does not exists a new instance is created.
try:
    obj = YourModel.objects.get(id=your_model_id)
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    obj = YourModel(code='0001', name='Example')
    obj.save()

# Equivalent simpler code.
your_model_instance = YourModel.objects.get_or_create(id=your_model_id, defaults={'code': '0001', 'name': 'Example'})
```

Even though, you can do *whatever you want* in your `except` clause. But remember that `pass` should only be placed in an `except` if you don't care about that exception and that is not your case.

More info about `get_object_or_404` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) and more info about `get_or_create` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).